# what's wrong with my .travis.yml file?

Tags: python, flask, travis-ci

I don't want this to sound like a vague question but I am not sure why my app is not being built on travis CI. for the record it's not like the app actually needs to be unit tested in this way but I wanted to try it. All that it says on travis is that it's loading but no builds are happening. Here is the github repository and here is the .travis.yml file.

https://github.com/DavidAwad/SpaceShare  Building here.
https://travis-ci.org/DavidAwad/SpaceShare

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.7"
  - "3.4"
services: 
  - mongodb
install: # command to install dependencies
  - "pip install -r requirements.txt"
# command to run tests
script: python test.py

notifications:
  email:
    - davidawad64@gmail.com

sudo: false
```

Comment: I believe that `-mongodb` needs a space after the hyphen

Comment: added! Still not building though :(

Comment: Did you add the web hook on GitHub for Travis? There is also a button to send a test payload.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that on github I had listed a URL that I was planning to use for my future hosting. Github was sending a webhook to THAT url expecting an instance of Travis to be running on there. Which of course it wasn't.